# Invoking Glympse fro HTML

Tags: html, protocols, handler, glympse

I'm trying to do a simple test consisting of invoking Glympse from HTML, but don't get any result. This is what I'm coding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p><a href="glympse:">test</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not a question. Please give us more detail as to what platform you're on, and what it is that you're trying to do, so we can better help you out.

Comment: I'm running the attached HTML code in my Safari browser (IOS 10.2.1). I would expect to launch/open the Glympse app I previously downloaded, but nothing is happening. I was just following what I read in Glympse URI Schema:

Comment: The [Glympse Application Protocol docs](https://developer.glympse.com/docs/core/app/rpc/general/overview) suggest a different scenario than the one you're attempting.  What is it you're trying to accomplish?  Glympse provides a number of [different APIs](https://developer.glympse.com/docs/core); there may be one more suited to your intended use.